# jenkins pipeline build inside container

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-build-flow

I am trying to run build step inside docker container. Here is my `Jenkinsfile`

```
    pipeline {
        agent { label 'slave1' }
        stages {
            stage ('Build') {
                agent {
                    docker {image 'node:8'}
                }
                steps {
                    sh "npm install"
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            failure {
                script {
                    echo "TestRail failed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But step is failing with following error

```
    [Frontend@2] Running shell script
    + npm install
    npm WARN mycloud@1.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN mycloud@1.0.0 No license field.

    npm ERR! path /.npm
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno -13
    npm ERR! syscall mkdir
    npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'
    npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'
    npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir \'/.npm\'',
    npm ERR!   errno: -13,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
    npm ERR!   path: '/.npm' }
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
    npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
    npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
    npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
    [Pipeline] }
    $ docker stop --time=1 56e0023a9538d890a72a07bc3e57aa99b6c92d0adfc99f8e70117dd143e3d22b
    $ docker rm -f 56e0023a9538d890a72a07bc3e57aa99b6c92d0adfc99f8e70117dd143e3d22b
```

When I run the docker container by hand and then execute `npm install` everything works as expected.

If run the container as root `-u 0:0` then `npm install` passes

```
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node:8'
                    args '-u 0:0'
                }
            }
```

but jenkins workspace cleanup fails with :

```
        ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/mycompany/Frontend.git
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:888)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1155)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:120)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:90)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:77)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:50)
        at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git clean -fdx" returned status code 1:
    stdout: 
    stderr: warning: failed to remove node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/README.md: Permission denied
    warning: failed to remove node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/package.json: Permission denied
    warning: failed to remove node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/tasks/copy.js: Permission denied
    warning: failed to remove node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/LICENSE-MIT: Permission denied
    warning: failed to remove node_modules/meow/readme.md: Permission denied
```

Here I am trying to run build process inside docker container rather than running on build machine, this way I don't have to install package on build machine, it will come from container image.

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently I don't have access to my server so I can't test it , but did you tried `skipDefaultCheckout`and then checkout from the repository at the docker stage?

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'slave1' }

    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout true
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {image 'node:8'}
            }
            steps {
                checkout scm
                sh "npm install"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            script {
                echo "TestRail failed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My intention was to use default checkout and then run build steps inside the container, this way I don't have to install the packages on the build server. This isn't possible ?

Comment: @roy Before the cleanup stage did you tried to change the onwership of the files?

Comment: Hey man this worked for me, thanks a lot I really really mean it, you saved me on this one

Answer (score 0):

Use docker step from cloudbees instead of using it as an agent. Doing so, you will checkout on master and mount workspace into docker as a volume(implicitly done by docker plugin).

What is the user id of your Jenkins user? As far as I remember if your jenkins user has ID 1000 then you need not override the user, because the default node docker image has a user with 1000 as an ID and there shouldn’t be any file permission issue(for deleting files).

Excuse the syntax errors as am not at my machine

```
def image = docker.image(‘node:latest’)
image.pull()
image.inside(dockerOptions) {
   sh “npm”
   // my other logic
  }
```